# .NET 2 Applications - Port .NET 3.5 Code

Tags: .net

I am in a very frustrating situation. All .NET developments have been done using version 3.5 of the framework having agreed (over a year ago) we would no longer be using .NET 2. Most of the infrastructure has .NET 3.5 installed but it was discovered yesterday there are servers that are still using .NET 2.

Change management is a nightmare so a pragmatic decision was made to port the .NET 3.5 code required back to .NET 2. This has opened quite a big can of worms. Am I doing the right thing? I am concerned about having two versions of the code in .NET 2 and .NET 3.5. Different applications will be referencing pretty much the same code in different locations.

How would other people approach this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: I would fight tooth-and-nail *never* to have to downgrade an application like this. That's not 'pragmatic' at all. The main reason I could see it being 'needed' would be if the target server(s) had Windows 2000.

Comment: I wish I could say it was technical reasons that .NET 3.5 is not installed but the challenge will be bureaucratic.

Comment: If someone else is forcing you to backport to an older version, then I would lay responsibility for how to manage that - and responsibility for what happens as a result - firmly at their feet.

Comment: As pickypg said in his answer, just install 3.5 on the server.  Organize a meeting, and ask IT how much it will cost to install .Net 3.5.  Then give your estimate of how much it will cost to back port everything.  I'm pretty certain the cost of the backport will be more expensive than installing 3.5.  IT is there to serve the business, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with forcing the upgrade to .NET 3.5? I realize it might be a pain bureaucratically, but it is the right thing to do and it was the expected outcome in the first place.

Not to mention, why rewrite code for an older version of software when the fix (.NET 3.5) literally includes .NET 2, so any legacy .NET 2 applications will work exactly the same?

My opinion: don't rewrite code when it's simply the matter of installing the update.

Comment: My guess is they have server(s) still running Windows 2000 (can only install 2.0; not newer). That's its own can of worms, too.

Comment: You're probably right, in which case I'd say upgrade those too. Windows 2000 hasn't been supported since last year, which means open vulnerabilities sitting inside the company to pull a Sony.

Comment: These are Windows 2003 servers. The biggest hurdle here is politics.

Comment: @youwhut Fight it. It's silly to introduce bugs downgrading your entire code base when the answer is so blindingly simple. It will save _a lot_ of headache down the road to do it _right_ the first time around.

Comment: @pickypg The fight has started.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option I'd just get another server involved. This doesn't necessarily have to be another piece of hardware, it could just be a VM. If you've only got a limited number of external IP addresses, have some of the virtual hosts reverse proxy to the .NET 3.5 machines (but only for the sites that actually need it).

In other words, if you've got machine A hosting "abc.com", "def.com", "ghi.com", and "jkl.com", and only "abc.com" needs .NET 3.5, set up a VM that can host .NET 3.5 code (machine B), and have machine A reverse proxy "abc.com" to machine B. Done and done.

Comment: Although I appreciate the creative answer this is not realistic. We are talking about a company where I will be fighting hard for the .NET 3.5 upgrade. Introducing VMs etc... fat chance.

Comment: Well I have no idea about your company. At mine this would be preferable to investing man-hours into porting legacy code for no good reason. Compared to how much you'd spend converting in one direction or the other, this is a LOT cheaper. Management loves it when you save them money :)

Comment: Yep, I am very aware of how anti-agile this company is.